# Merging two files in PHP

Tags: php, merge, lcs

I'm working on a part of a webapp where users will be able to change the same file together and see the changes each other do (just like Google Drive currently do). But I'm stuck on the "see the changes each other do" and merging files parts.

I've seen this post : [How can I merge two versions of a file in PHP or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935216/how-can-i-merge-two-versions-of-a-file-in-php-or-javascript) and i've understood how to find le LCS between two part of a file. But I don't know what to do after this... When I'll got the LCS, I will have the part that are the same between the three files (mine, other user's, and original one) but what to do next ?

I can't use any system like SVN on this as there would be too many commit / update to keep things up to date on every user's browser.

Do you have any clue ?

Thank you !

Comment: You can try to find some good advice also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217241/whats-the-most-compact-way-to-store-diffs-in-a-database or https://www.google.com/search?q=storing+file+diffs+in+database or https://www.google.com/search?q=php+file+diff+class